# Should the behaviour of a function depend on the name of its variable?

Tags: elisp

Here is a short elisp code which shows that the behaviour of a function depends on the name of its variable.  Is this a bug?

A function is declared using a variable x.  When that function is called with a variable named anything other than x, it works as expected.  But if it is called with a variable named x, it fails!

My system is GNU Emacs 22.2.1 (powerpc-apple-darwin8.11.0, Carbon Version 1.6.0) of 2008-04-05 on g5.tokyo.stp.isas.jaxa.jp

---

Paste this on an emacs buffer, put the cursor after the last parehthesis and press \C-x\C-e to see that the function make-zero does now work correctly when called the second time.

```
(progn
  (defun make-zero (x) 
    "Simple function to make a variable zero."
    (set x 0))

  (setq x 10)

  (insert "\n Variable x is now equal to " (number-to-string x))

  (setq y 20)

  (insert "\n Variable y is now equal to " (number-to-string y))

  (insert "\n\n Let us apply make-zero to y")

  (make-zero 'y)

  (insert "\n Variable y is now equal to " (number-to-string y))

  (insert "\n\n Let us apply make-zero to x")

  (make-zero 'x)

  (insert "\n Variable x is now equal to " (number-to-string x))

  (insert "\n\n Why make-zero had no effect on x?  Is it because the name of the
variable in the definition of make-zero, namely 'x', is the same as the name of
the variable when make-zero was called?  If you change the name of the variable
in the definition of make-zero from x to z, this strange behaviour will
disappear.  This seems to be a bug in elisp."))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug so much as the nature of Elisp's (and Lisp in general) dynamic binding.  `'` doesn't pass a reference (that is, it's not like `&` in C/C++), it passes an unevaluated symbol; what it then evaluates to depends on the scope in which it's evaluated, which means it gets the `x` that's in scope inside the function.

In Lisp-think, the normal way around this would be to use a macro.

```
(defmacro make-zero (x) (list 'set x 0))
```

or

```
(require 'cl)
(defmacro make-zero (x) `(set ,x 0))
```

Comment: No need to require cl.el for the second example. It should work just as well without it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug.  It'd be worth your while reading the manual entry for [Scoping Rules For Variable Bindings](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Variable-Scoping.html#Variable-Scoping).

The function you wrote calls `set`, which takes a symbol (the value of the first argument) and changes its value to the value of the 2nd argument.  The `make-zero` you wrote binds `x` locally to its input argument, so when you pass in the symbol `x`, set changes the first binding for `x` it finds, which happens to be the local binding.

Here's a different example, let's say you just had the following:

```
(defun print-something (something)
  (set 'something "NEW VALUE")
  (insert something))

(print-something "OLD")    ; inserts "NEW VALUE"
```

Looking at that snippet of code, does it make sense that the `set` line changes the local value of `something`?

It doesn't matter whether or not there's a global setting for the symbol `something`.

Another example is the following:

```
(defvar x "some global value") ;# could have used setq here
(let ((x "local binding"))
  (set 'x "new value"))
```

Which binding would you expect the `set` line to change?  The one created by the `let` or the global one created by `defvar`?

The function you wrote is (pretty much) doing exactly the same thing as the `let`, you're creating a local binding for a variable which is seen before the global one.

If you want to pass around a reference to a variable then the only safe way to do that is via [macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/elisp/Macros.html#Macros), which I recommend, but not until you've grasped the basics of lisp (b/c macros are definitely more complicated).  That said, don't let me stop you from diving into macros if that's your passion.

A good introduction to programming Emacs lisp can be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/index.html).

[geekosaur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425825/should-the-behaviour-of-a-function-depend-on-the-name-of-its-variable/5425952#5425952) does a nice job of showing how you'd achieve what you want.